# How to show the song download represented by duration time of it

Tags: actionscript-3

What i'm trying to do is to show the song download progress in form of song duration time. For example: *00:00, 01:05, 02:14, 03:58, .... 04:13* being *04:13* the song total duration. So far i have this code:

```
var soundClip:Sound;
var sTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(0.1);

function init() {
soundClip = new Sound();
soundClip.load(new URLRequest("magneto.mp3"));
//soundClip.load(new URLRequest("making.mp3"));
soundClip.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, soundLoaded);
soundClip.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, soundLoading);
}
init();

function convertTime(millis:Number):String{
    var displayMinutes:String;
    var displaySeconds:String;
    var Minutes:Number = (millis % (1000*60*60)/(1000*60));
    var Seconds:Number = ((millis % (1000*60*60)) % (1000*60))/1000;
    if(Minutes<10){
        displayMinutes = "0"+Math.floor(Minutes);
    }else{
        displayMinutes = Math.floor(Minutes).toString();
    }
    if(Seconds<10){
        displaySeconds = "0"+Math.floor(Seconds);
    }else{
        displaySeconds = Math.floor(Seconds).toString();
    }
    return displayMinutes + ":" + displaySeconds;
}


function soundLoaded(e:Event) {
    soundClip.play(0,0,sTransform);
}
function soundLoading(e:ProgressEvent) {
    trace(convertTime(soundClip.length));
}
```

As you can see, i'm testing it out with two songs, according to the code above the duration time of both are: 03:52 and 11:28 but according to the window these two songs last 03:52 and 05:44. [Here](https://rapidshare.com/files/2687020915/Pregunta.rar) is the code and both mp3 files.

Thank you.

EDIT:I'm analizing this [page](http://www.enladisco.com/seleccion-baladas/haciendo-el-amor-de-la-nada---air-supply) wicht play the song making.mp3, after debbuging it i realized that there is a value wicht is passed to the player, and go this way: *0, 0, 2664, 7576,...344370* these values are shown as*00:00, 01:05, 02:14, 03:58, .... 04:13* as the download progress. Knowing where this data come from would solve my problem, initially i thought it would be obtein through length propety but this only worked well for the magneto.mp3 file not for both songs.

On the whole i want to show:

00:00, 00:23, 01:23...03:57(where 03:57 is the duration time of any song) as the download progress.

Thank you for helping me. Cheers :)

Comment: How can i get it show the rigth duration time in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no problems and your technique is correct.

You only need to fetch the total duration at the end of the download. The value of the file length changes as more data is retrieved. If your download stops before reaching the end, you will only have the length of the incomplete file. Add another handler possibly to check for errors, and if fired, let the user know that the file download is still incomplete.

Update: I figured it out. Add a call to `convertTime()` in the `soundLoaded()` method.

What is happening is that the file length is being updated in the PROGRESS event handler. But the final length is often only available in the COMPLETE event, because the PROGRESS event handler is called only when the file download is incomplete and not after it is ready.

Keep the `convertTime()` call in the PROGRESS event handler as you do presently.

```
private function soundLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    soundClip.play(0, 0, sTransform);
    trace(convertTime(soundClip.length));
}
```

This should do it.

Update 2: This is a known issue reported online at many forums. The length of any sound file sampled at less than 44 khz is reported incorrectly while the download is in progress. It's only after the download completes that the correct duration is reported. This only affects SWF files version 9 or less.

Changing the output SWF to version 10+ fixes the issue.

Comment: Thank Pranav, i want to do it like [this](http://www.enladisco.com/seleccion-baladas/haciendo-el-amor-de-la-nada---air-supply) it show its download in form of duration time in progressive form. That part 00:00 is result of this javascript operation :`var t_total = (total / 1000),
                        fminutes = Math.floor(t_total / 60),
                        fseconds = Math.ceil(t_total % 60);`In the song making.mp3 that **total** is loaded  progressively this way: 0,2664,7576,..,344370(05:45) ¿Where do i get that value?and ¿what does it mean?

Comment: It's funny, it work well when the duration time(`soundClip.length`) is divided by **two**. But why two?. It turn into complex issue because have to do whith the modification of those mp3 files.

Comment: I looked up this issue in a bit more detail today, and it seems to be a known bug in the Sound class when working with files of <= 22 khz (making.mp3 is 22 khz, while magento.mp3 is 44 khz). You'll find many reports of this bug on the internet. The best solution seems to be to wait till the COMPLETE event and then checking the file length.

Comment: Additionally, this bug only occurs in Flash Player 9 or below. If you convert the SWF into 10+ format, the length value is displayed correctly even during the progress events. This might be the solution you're finally looking for. Added an update to this effect in the answer above.

Comment: Know, i understood so this occurs in Flash Player 9 or below. Thank you Pranav.